# where are the function key row keys explained for the dell inspiron N5010, what does the "A" key do?

Tags: keyboard

1. What does the "A" key do?
2. What does the key to its right do (looks like a plug or an AA battery).
3. What does the key to the left of the "A" key do?
4. What does the key to the right of the Fn12 key do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Keyboard in question]

- The "A" key (F2) is your WiFi network on/off toggle (it's an antenna, not an "A").
- On the F3 key is a picture of a battery, and should bring up your Battery Health Meter when pushed.
- The F1 key toggles between the notebook's monitor and an external monitor (if you have it attached), or both.
- The key to the right of the F12 key toggles your touchpad on and off.

For all/some of these keys to work with these extended features you'll need the Dell utilities installed (I believe it's the Dell "Quickset" utility).